# 'Do-until' in a table row by row until the first colored cell found in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, do-while

I have a table in excel with 7 columns users can place their inputs. After placing their inputs, they have a validation macro to run, which colors the cells with invalid values to red. I want to create a summary sheet about these errors after this coloring with VBA macro, but only if there are any colored cell in the table.
If there is at least one red cell somewhere in the table range, this summary sheet should be created, else a MsgBox should pop up telling that there were no errors. I want to create the easiest way to do that, something like this:
The problem is with this I got the "Validation errors found, please check the Errors sheet" message, even if I do not have red cells.

```
Sub errorListCreation(Sheet1 As Worksheet)
Dim isColored As Boolean
isColored = False
    For Each Acell In Sheet1.Range("A2", Range("K" & Sheet1.usedRange.Rows.Count))
        With Acell
            If Acell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                isColored = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next Acell

    If isColored = True Then
        MsgBox "Validation errors found, please check the Errors sheet. "
        For Each errorList In Worksheets
            If errorList.Name = "Errors" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets("Errors").Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        Next
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Errors"
    Else: MsgBox "Validation complete, please check the reconciliation sheet."
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue? What exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is that is there an other way to do that? As my solution is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is no useful error description. Can you tell which error you get and in which line? or what your code does vs what you expected? That would help us. Also a screenshot of the table could help understanding the actual issue.

Comment: Using formatting such as shading as a way of assigning a second value to a cell is an antipattern. Instead, create another column that holds that value and use conditional formatting to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsColored(ByVal Rng As Range) As Boolean
    IsColored = (Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0))
End Function

Public Sub ColorFinder(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim ErrorFound As Boolean

    Dim InputTable As ListObject
    Set InputTable = ws.ListObjects("Table4") 'probably no good idea to hard code the table name (at least use a meaningful name)

    With InputTable.DataBodyRange
        Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
        For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            For iCol = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                If IsColored(.Cells(iRow, iCol)) Then
                    ErrorFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iCol
            If ErrorFound Then Exit For
        Next iRow
    End With

    If ErrorFound Then
        MsgBox "Errors found", vbCritical
    Else
        MsgBox "No errors found", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
    ColorFinder Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

On the following sheet

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Assume the above  worksheet "Sheet1" with a ListObject "Table4".</sup>*

you will get

> "Errors found"

Comment: Yes but I do not have complete rows in red, only some cells in some rows.

Comment: Can you please advise on my post below?

Comment: @Looz please edit your original question and show a screenshot then.

Comment: Thanks, please find the screenshot link in the modified question

Comment: Thanks but my picture was only a part of the total. The real inputs contains millions of rows, so I do not want to count here all the errors, only want to check if there is at least one, and if it founds one, the for loop should stop and then my other code starts to copy the exact errors to the error sheet.
Thats why I used in my example the Exit for, because after the isColored became True, its not necessary to check further.

Comment: @Looz Well, then check again.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still have the "Errors found" message, even if I do not have red cells. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Looz check which cell it is that is detected as red `.Cells(iRow, iCol).Select` right after `ErrorFound = True` should select it. And check its format. The cell that is then selected is the issue. • And make sure no conditional formattings are hiding the actual red colored cell.

Comment: I had a hidden column with red cells :D Thank you very much for your help!